# how to set LaTeX font size in millimeter?

Tags: latex, fonts, size, font-size

I need to set the font size in millimeters in my LaTeX document. how can I do that?

thank you!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Are you using Type 1 fonts (that is, infinitely scalable fonts)? If not, you'll need to do something like `\usepackage{lmodern}` (that selects my preferred fonts, the Latin Modern version of Computer Modern). Then just enter a command like

```
\fontsize{8mm}{9mm}\selectfont
```

and the following text will be in a font 8 mm high on a 9 mm baseline. If you need to set the size of more than a small amount of text in this way, you will probably have to go into the document class definition -- good luck; I stay as far away from those as I possibly can.

Comment: To be more specific, the sizing parameters (which adjust when you type \small, \large, etc.) are defined for the standard classes in size{10,11,12}.clo. Make a new one of them and hack away...

Comment: All works perfectly, I just want add that \fontsize{size}{skip} must be after \begin{document}