# Why would LaTeX ignore the font size in the documentclass

Tags: text, latex, formatting, text-formatting

I have a LaTeX file. I'm experimenting with trying to reduce the font size (this is related to my other question here [LaTeX - Changing the font size for a document, but in the preamble, not the document class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636647/latex-changing-the-font-size-for-a-document-but-in-the-preamble-not-the-docum) ).

The LaTeX file is generated from another programme. I have edited it to start with

```
\documentclass[4pt,a4paper,english]{report}
```

i.e. I am trying to make the text really small. However it doesn't work. I change that `4pt` to anything and the font size is the same.

When running pdflatex on it, I get this message printed out.

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [4pt].
```

That might explain why the error message is

What could be going on here? How do I make it use the font size in the `documentclass` definition?

Comment: A bit off-topic, if you have some time, check out xelatex, which offers far superior font handling.

Answer (score 11):

You can use only

```
10pt|11pt|12pt
```

in the default [documentclass](http://www.nada.kth.se/~carsten/latex/class.html)

I think you have to redefine the main text command to support smaller (unreadable) font sizes

Answer (score 11):

There is no option `4pt` defined for documentclass `article`, as it was already mentioned. So your `4pt` is simply not recognized by LaTeX.

You can however use [`extsizes`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=extsizes) package, which allows some more size options: 8 through 12, 14, 17 and 20pt. However no support for 4pt. There exist other packages that allow for non-standard default sizes, listed at the same page.

Answer (score -1):

Use `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,english]{article}` and then specify `\tiny` after `\begin{document}`.